# Get itunes link for app before submitting

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I read in another post that you can submit the app without the binary but I based on what I have seen this is no longer possible. It seems you cannot submit without the binary and the binary is submitted through the application loader. Is there any other known way to get the itunes/app store link to my app before I submit the binary?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up using - itms://itunes.apple.com/app/id?mt=8 
This seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: I had better success with the http://phobos.apple.com link. Using the itms link I got two popups.

Comment: if you ever change the name of your app, this will break things.

Answer (score 123):

- *The manual way:*

Your should copy your "Apple ID" from iTunes connect and use this link:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/APPNAME/idXXXXXXXXX

Would open the US store ("APPNAME" is that app name and XXXXXXXXX is the "Apple ID". You can use more general method (**Recommended**):

http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX

and replace "XXXXXXXXX" with your "Apple ID" (from iTunes connect - after creating the app there).

Pay attention that those would open safari if you won't preprocess them, You could also use itms:// to open iTunes directly.

Comment: [Apple] Creating easy-to-read short links to the App Store for your apps and company: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html

Comment: `http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX `    This is the only valid way to open apps with arabic names , Thank u

Comment: I dont know why this answer is not accepted, many thanks to you man saved my day +1

Comment: @gurkanstack There is a very specific example. Please elaborate what you are missing.

Answer (score 76):

The easiest way to do this now is through **iTunes Connect**. Once you create an app there is a link to 'View in App Store'. Even if you haven't uploaded a binary yet you can click this link to get your App Store link.

The other answers work too but this generates your url for you. This is the URL it creates with my info removed *(replace app-name and the numbers after /id with your own)*:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-name/id12345678?ls=1&mt=8
```

Comment: this should be an accepted answer, b/c this is an iTunes Connect who tells you what the link is / would be. Thanks!

Comment: Presently to be found under App Store > App Information at the very bottom under 'Additional Information' to save you the time to look for the link. Seems to still link to the app store in my default country rather than the more general user's default.

Comment: What if my app name has contain "space" in the name like ... my App name is "App Name"

Comment: @Govaadiyo if your App name is "App Name", then use https://apps.apple.com/us/app/app-name/id12345678

Comment: This button is not visible from the beginning.

Comment: From where can we get the ID?

Comment: As of 8 July 2021, this doesn't work if you have only just created the app, and not submitted it. The resulting page will be empty, forcing you to copy the ID and formatted name, and then you hope that you got it right. It's really a very poor system.

Answer (score 37):

Once you create application in iTunes for submission under **App Information tab** click in **View on App Store** you will get app link.

[image]

**Option 2: (In new update this is no longer available) you can create as below**

```
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/your-appname/id123456?mt=8
```

Note : Just replace **app name** and **numbers after /id with your app-id** in above link

Comment: In the new appstoreconnect website, this link is no longer displayed before the app is released. Unless it is hidden somewhere else?

Comment: did you find it on appstore connect?

Comment: In new update this is no longer available. If this button show you will get link.

Comment: this button is no longer available.

Comment: i know but for old app which created before this change made, they can see this button.

Answer (score 25):

Use this url example and just change your Apple ID at the end! **Replace only the numbers!**

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id111111111

You can find the value of your Appple ID by login into your App Store Connect and navigating to 'My Apps' under the 'App Information' -> 'General Information' -> 'Apple ID'

This url format works always and it is particularly helpful if you need the link before you publish your app

Comment: What should go for XXXXX here? The Apple ID?

Comment: It helps me since I need to add shared url link in my project before release.

Comment: @KirillKarmazin you need to replace the XXXXXXXXX with your Apple ID and it should look something like the example I gave above after I edit my answer

Answer (score 19):

The standard URL is:

```
http://itunes.com/apps/yourlowercaseappname
```

Comment: I did not find this to be true in iOS 6.1 it seems like you always need to specify the id and it should be itunes.apple.com rather than only itunes.com - so it seems like it is not possible to do what you required before you release the app. A workaround might be to point at the developer page and at the next release to point directly at the app url.

Comment: @Mike may be this is not right way to get redirected link, most of user wants link which can be redirect directly to that particular application.

Answer (score 14):

As of today and for reference, I would say the best option is `@"http://itunes.apple.com/app/%@/id%@?mt=8"`, inserting:

1. your application lowercase name,
2. your application ID.

In fact, this is essentially the link you can get for your application on your app's page in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) (iTunes Connect > Manage Your Apps > Your App > View in App Store). Minus some parameters (which seems - between other unidentified things - to link to a precise country).

I thinks it's better than the `itms://...` one because this one redirects you to the iTunes Store on your device, which is not the App Store. You're then redirected, etc. The `http://...` link seems to be directly hooked to the App Store app.

Comment: u can omit the app name actually

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by: "this one redirects you to the iTunes Store on your device, which is not the App Store."

Comment: @Mungbeans An iOS device has both iTunes Store and App Store apps. The first one is for music, video... while only the second one is for apps. Redirecting to iTunes Store for an app will just open the app which itself will redirect you to the App Store app.

Comment: Does app store connect has app id as well?

Answer (score 11):

Remember http://**itunes**.apple.com/app/id[Apple_ID] is gone. It will work for the old links and it should work fine for new ones too maybe, but to be safe use the new https://apps.apple.com/app/id[Apple_ID]

Answer (score 8):

You can get application link before uploading your binary file on iTunes Connect.

You just need to upload your meta data using iTunes Connect. And after submitting these data you will get Apple ID. And by this ID you can get the URL for your application.

e.g. http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=appID

where appID="Your application ID when you submit the meta data"

Please check this. It is working here. And If you still have any problem then please let me know. I will help you out to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Apple's iTunes Connect documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW15) the **View on App Store** link is only available if at least one version of the app has had it's status set to **Ready for Sale**.

Having said that you can still see what the actual link will be, you just will not be able to load the page.

Answer (score 5):

Best way to get app link is

1. login to itunes connect
2. Go to My Apps -> create app record if
   you don't have any.
3. select your app -> go to App Information
   section
4. At bottom of the page check additional information
   section, there is a link called "View on App Store". Click on the
   link and you will get exact URL for your app.Copy-Paste and Enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

Apple has [a documentation for creating easy-to-read app links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1633/_index.html). If your app name is specified, creating your links with this way is much more clear.

Comment: let me try above link

Answer (score 5):

It seems the app id is now the Apple ID in the itunesconnect page. Go to App Information and scroll down until you see Apple ID. That is your app id.

http://itunes.apple.com/app/id[Apple_ID]

Comment: Is this visible in app store connect too?

Comment: Yes. It is the exact same procedure. I didn't notice any difference. Seems like App Store Connect is just a rebranding of iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://itunesconnect.apple.com,
if not yet created, create a new App.

Open it and in the first screen (**AppStore -> App information -> General**) there is a field called "**Apple ID**" with the *id number*.

[image]

Copy and use it. Is this one.

Answer (score 3):

If AdWords does not allow a link to iTunes, this will solve it...

If you use the link generated at the bottom of iTunesConnect, and you are selling internationally, you will find **/us/** or **/gb/** or **/de/** etc that indicates the language of the relevant store. Adwords will not approve a link with the language indicated.

Why?

Because Adwords does not accept redirects and unmatched URLs. If the link is to the USA store, but the Adword test originates in Germany, then a redirect is detected. Of course, this behavior is correct because no matter what the link says the user will go to her local app store.

**Solution**: Edit the link from iTunes Connect. Strip out unneeded info. Simply match the display and final URL, disregarding any message about length in the display URL warning text.

URL copied from iTunes:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/this-is-my-app-name/id1111111111?ls=1&mt=8

Edited URL suitable for AdWords

DISPLAY URL
itunes.apple.com/app/id111111111

FINAL URL
http://itunes.apple.com/app/id111111111

*notes*: 
- appstore.com     is a redirect
- itunes.apple.com    by itself is a redirect. Only **in full as above** does it go directly to your app page.
- When one URL - no matter how valid - redirects, then the result is mismatched URLs.

/gb

Answer (score 3):

1- Go > https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

2- My Apps > Select Your App

3- App Store > App Information > View On App Store

Comment: I am not able to view see View on Appstore

Comment: try searching app-id on itunes or you can use fnd.io to find your app

Answer (score 1):

The best simple link is
`http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX`.

You can get id from your App Information in http://itunesconnect.apple.com.