# How to avoid "App is allready authorized" with Facebook SDK 3.1

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Every time i want to login through the Facebook idk, safari will be opened and tells me that my app is allready authorized. But i dont want to show this screen everytime a user logs in with Facebook. I followed the instructions [over here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) to implement facebook login functionality. If the auth button is clicked i simple call the openSessionWithAllowLoginMethod which then handles the rest for me. But i dont how to apply the functionality, that it wont show the authorized screen everytime, to this code ? I would really appreciate some tips or hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill out every field related to your app in the Native iOS App section of the Basic Settings in the App Dashboard. If these fields are not configured, we can't drive traffic to your app or the iOS App Store. In addition, we use the iOS Bundle ID to streamline authentication for users who already authenticated your app. [Pro-tip 3: Complete all iOS App Settings](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. But we still developing so there is no Appstore ID and i also cant find the SSO Option in our settings ?

Comment: just set iOS bundle id, you must have "Configured for iOS SSO" inside developers.facebook.com profile

Comment: As a side note, you can get the app store ID if you submit a binary on iTunes Connect and then cancel it right away: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137426/get-itunes-link-for-app-before-submitting)

Comment: where is located "Configured for iOS SSO" inside developers.facebook.com profile?