# How to implement opening AppStore page before the app is on the market?

Tags: ios, app-store

I found the following code sniplet here:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/???"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Now assume app would know if there is a new version available at the market (using own server) how to implement redirecting2/displaying correct appStore page if my app isn't at the market yet. I need to know the link before I will upload it to apple. How to know what the url it will be?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137426/get-itunes-link-for-app-before-submitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have your Developer Account, you can start the app submission process. Fill out all the details, etc, but just don't upload your binary.

Once you've gotten to the very end, and it's ready for you to upload a binary, iTunes Connect will actually give you your iTunes URL. You should be able to copy and paste that into your app before building it, and uploading your final binary.

Alternatively, you could always use a URL on one of your own servers and just do a redirect to the iTunes URL. This way you can update that outside of the app. This is actually what I used to do before Apple made the URL available ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

> You have to create an app record on `iTunes Connect`. Just fill in some
>   dummy data to start with. Once you have the app record there will be
>   an Apple ID for it, something like 123456789.

'

> If you are using Appirater then this is the number you need to fill in
>   in the header, otherwise the link (copied out of appirater) is

```
itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=APP_ID
```

where APP_ID is the number you got from iTunes Connect.