# Get id of itunes link before upload it in to the app store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get itunes link for app before submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137426/get-itunes-link-for-app-before-submitting)

I want to provide **`ituens link in share app page before submitting page`**

when i was go throw some sample apps itunes links they have the following pattern.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cap-that!/id542207157

https://itunes.apple.com/app/cap-that!/id542207157

in both links we have **`idxxxxxxx`** how we get this id of my application

and is the location id us/en is optional..?

Answer (score 1):

When you create app in iTunes connect you will receive Apple ID for that app. So create app and then when you click on it to edit details you will have all those details in top left corner like this:

http://cl.ly/image/0I3y2I3N213c

Here you can see that my app id is 472985456 so just add the rest of the url to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

First, just create app in iTunes Connect and fill necessary data.

Then there will be one link like "View on AppStore" or something similar. When you click on link, then it will be your app link when your app will become live. Currently no app will be opened because you have not uploaded app.

So, by this way, you can get your app url, and use it in your code for sharing and create bundle then submit.

Cheers and Enjoy Coding!