# Can an app know what its url in the app store will be?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a requirement for an app to share a link to itself on the app store via social sharing i.e. this sort of thing:

"I've been using this great app, you can get it at: "

Therefore the app needs to know what its app store url will be before it is submitted to the app store, is this possible?

Comment: Which app store do you mean?

Comment: iOS - the SO "app-store" tag is for iOS but I guess that's not very explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your app ID to construct the URL.  You can get the ID from the iTunesConnect page for the app, then construct the URL thus:

```
#define APP_ID 653451876

NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cap-that!/id%d",APP_ID];
```

See there https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764735/877032

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to make an educated guess using the current format of the iTunes URLs which is:

`https://itunes.apple.com/{country_code}/app/{app_name}/id{app_id}?mt=8`

Once you create a "New App" in iTunes Connect, you should get your App id, so you could plug it into the URL.

Another alternative, if you have the ability to make a simple HTTP call from your app then you could simply bake the boilerplate portion of the URL into the code (e.g. `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/{app_name}/id{app_id}?mt=8`), and then when your app launches, reach out to the URL where you've specified the proper id of your app. Save that in `NSUserDefaults` and construct the URL in code from that point on.

If you do not have a website or custom back-end, you could look into a service like [Parse](https://www.parse.com) to help you out.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

If you are the developer of the app, in google play store you can know it, for example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.madfingergames.deadzone
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whawhawhat.referencejquery

You see that there is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id= and then the Package name 
which is something like: com.mycompany.myfirstapp

In the iTunes store an app gets an id so it's not possible.

Comment: It is possible with iOS.