# How do you provide mobile app to press before release?

Tags: android, ios

I have often heard that you should start your marketing early and that it is good to contact press etc about a review of the game a while before the release of the game (2-3 weeks maybe) so if they want to write a review they could publish it on the same day you release. But how do you provide a review copy of the game for iOS and Android?

On Steam it is very easy, you can just create press keys that you then send out and the reviewers and press can access the game with the code before official release as if it was any other game. But there is nothing like this on iOS and Android?

On Android I guess one option would be to provide an apk of the game, but that is kind of a pain to install and I doubt everyone even know how to install a stand alone apk on the device.

On iOS it seems even worse? If I want to test my app before release I need to install provisional profile on my devices, and I think I also need to add those devices to my developer portal. So you can't just provide a file there I think.. and I don't think many press people would go through all those steps to try out the game.

So how to do this, and what do other developer and you do to tackle this? Is there even a way?

Comment: are you asking related to iOS or andriod

Comment: if it is in iOS see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137426/get-itunes-link-for-app-before-submitting

Answer (score 0):

Both platforms allow you to put a build in beta testing. That's how it supposed to be done.

To start beta test on Android open developer console website, go to your application and configure beta testing in APK section.

To start beta test on iOS go to iTunes Connect website, open My apps section, choose your app then go to Testflight section and start external testing.

Comment: Thank you! 
As for Android, in open beta I get a link that I share if I understand correctly that I can give to anyone and they can download it? 

On iOS though, it seems I need to add email adresses for them to access the game? So I need to ask press for their email to use (i assume the same email as they use to sign in on their device)? If this is the case the system on Android seem much better, but there is no way to do this with just give a link on iOS?

Comment: As I can remember, distribution of beta builds for android was done through Google Plus group...