# 'View in App Store' link not working in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have an app that has passed review and is now '*Pending Developer Release*'.

My client would like to see the App Store listing and have the URL on hand for their website, however the '*View in App Store*' link is not working. The page it opens is a HTTP ERROR 404 page saying

> This itunes.apple.com page can’t be found.

How can I get this working?
Thanks.

Comment: By the looks of it, it seems the app has not been released before and hence that link doesn't work. It will once you guys release the app. Anyways, you might also want to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764735/2857130

Answer (score 0):

It's very annoying; we had the same issue. Even if you push the "Release" button and Apple tells you you've released the app, **the link does not work for a certain period of time**. Wait and keep your fingers crossed until the app is indexed/searchable on the App Store.