# How to compose App store link [React-Native]

Tags: ios, react-native

when composing the app-link to the app-store, is the APP_STORE_ID is the AppleID found in the screen-shot down below?

```
export const APP_STORE_LINK = `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/${APP_NAME}/id${APP_STORE_ID}?mt=8`;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is the same

Comment: This is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137426/get-itunes-link-for-app-before-submitting

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh Thank you very much ... clear enough