# Create appstore's Link of my app before uploading to appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, mobile-application

I am trying to make appstore's link of my app through which user would be redirected to my app's page on appstore.
I am trying to create this link before publishing the app to app store.
i also have buttons like share and rate in my app where i redirect the user to app store that is why i need link before uploading to appstore.

Comment: Its not possible. Only after first upload you can give the link as well.

Comment: You can get appstore link before you publish the app. Once you create a new app in appstoreconnect you can get the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get itunes link for app before submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137426/get-itunes-link-for-app-before-submitting)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should create your Application in App Store Connect.
Then Go to App Information section and copy your Apple ID number.

Then use this id for url https://itunes.apple.com/idxxxxxxxx. Thats your link.
Check with existing applications (if you have one).