# How to open directly our app in apple store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

How to open directly my application in apple store ?
I have try with this, but it will open itunes app not apple store app

```
Linking.openURL(
  'itms-apps://apps.apple.com/id/app/halojasa/id1492671277?l=id'
).catch(err => {
  console.log('Error from rate us ', err)
})
```

Comment: do you have LSApplicationQueriesSchemes inside your info.plist ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you have to add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` to info.plist file.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>itms-apps</string>
</array>
```

and if you use can use `canOpenURL` method. it will prompt you error

```
const link = 'itms-apps://apps.apple.com/id/app/halojasa/id1492671277?l=id';
Linking.canOpenURL(link).then(supported => {
  supported && Linking.openURL(link);
}, (err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: How can you get your `halojasa` and `id1492671277`?

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153876/1871024